# Question color is too light

Tags: feature-request, design, accessibility

The color of the question titles on https://music.stackexchange.com/ is #817bd3, which does not follow the [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/).

It'd be great to darken the color.

---

From http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/ :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I agree completely, and I've noticed also that not only is the color slightly too faint, but that contrasted with the bright orange background it is (to me at least) a little jarring:

[image: I dunno... visit Music.SE/questions?]

For now, I actually created a *tiny* little userscript which allows one to customize the color to their own liking:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Music.SE Question Color
// @version      0.1
// @description  Changes the color of music.SE question titles
// @author       theonlygusti
// @match        http://music.stackexchange.com/questions
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.question-hyperlink').css('color', '#123456');
    });
}(jQuery));
```

I'm not going to lie, I actually quite liked my default color of `#123456`:

[image: Yep, no alt text here, can't be bothered. Sorry.]

Comment: The corresponding [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/) script would be just `@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
    
    @-moz-document domain("music.stackexchange.com") {
    .question-hyperlink {
      color: #123456;
    }
    }`. (FWIW, I find the current colour #817bd3 completely fine.)